# SQLmap specified HTTP request file 'request.txt' does not exist

Tags: веб-программирование, sqlmap, pentesting

Я хочу расковырять уязвимость sql injection в приложении bwapp. Уязвимость нашел, POST запрос с передачей данных через уязвимый параметр сохранил в файл request.txt:

`request.txt`:

```
POST /sqli_6.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 24
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost/sqli_6.php
Cookie: security_level=0; PHPSESSID=ocd0poooch53fqanru1ajijj94
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

title=hulk&action=search
```

Теперь запускаю sqlmap:

```
sqlmap -r request.txt -p title
```

Тут же возникает ошибка:

```
[16:26:49] [CRITICAL] specified HTTP request file 'request.txt' does not exist
```

Почему она произошла и как ее исправить и запустить sqlmap?

Файл находится в директории, из которой я запускаю sqlmap:

```
archlinux% ls
hash.txt  main.py  request.txt  sql.txt  test.py
```